# How to use jqgrid jqid method?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm still struggling with getting jqgrid's viewGridRow function to handle grids that have column names that include spaces. I came up with a hack to replace spaces with underscores but was told that that I should be using jqID instead. Specifically,

> If you want modify the code you should better use $.jgrid.jqID instead of replacement of blanks to undescores. The function $.jgrid.jqID are used in the most places of jqGrid code, but still not everywhere. The problem it very easy. It one have meta-characters as the part of id and one want to use the id as a part of the jQuery selector one have to escape the characters. The method $.jgrid.jqID do exactly the job.

Upon looking at the source code inside grid.base.js, I see that the function is defined as

```
$.extend($.jgrid,{
    jqID : function(sid){
        return String(sid).replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]\^`{|}~]/g,"\\$&");
    }
});
```

which leads me to believe that it should be perhaps used in the beforeProcessing() function to modify the cell IDs? Regardless, I don't see that the regex, as it currently exists, specifically handles spaces.

Oleg, if you're out there, help!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

D'oh!! As soon as I hit submit, I realized that Oleg meant to modify the jqID function to add spaces to the regex string. That seems to do the trick.

Comment: Any way is good if it solves the problem. I wrote about `jqID` after you posted the suggestion to modify ids. In general I prefer to have more exact description of the problem before I recommend something. The usage of blanks in the ids not always make problems in the current version of jqGrid. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BlanksInIds.htm). If your problem are still not solved it would be good if you post some simple demo which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can... after I downloaded the most recent version of jqgrid, I found that the spaces were not a problem with one grid, but were with another that was being called in the exact same way. The datasource is a db with millions of records so am not sure how I could post an example.

Comment: I asked you *to prepare* a small demo. You can just post code which fill grid having `datatype: 'local'` with at least one line of the data.